# StreamWriter skip items to serialize in foreach loop

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I'm having trouble with StreamWriter when serializing a big amount of objects in a foreach loop. Here's my code :

```
 public bool Export(ItemToSerialize it){
   try{
     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(MySettings.ExportPath, randomFileName + ".xml"))){
       XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemToSerialize));    
       ser.Serialize(sw,it);
      }
      return true;
    } 
    catch{throw;}
 } 

public bool ExportAll(){
  List<ItemToSerialize> lst = RetrieveListToSerialize();
  foreach(ItemToSerialize it in lst){
    Export(it);
  }
}
```

When I have a lot of data to export, it skips most of them. At first, I though that I had to flush the writer but flush / close when the export is done doesn't change anything.

What is surprising is that when I add a sleep (`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`), it works. Most surprising, when I disminuish the sleep at 500ms, it keeps skipping some of them.

I suspect that it's writing faster than the writer can open / close or simply write. However, I expect the Export function not to return until the file is totally written. Is there something like a 'background' task when writing with a StreamWriter ?

Because with the provided code, I really don't understand this behaviour.

Thanks !

Comment: are you sure, that `randomFileName` is really random?

Comment: How is `randomFileName` created?  Is it based on `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: You're right, random filename is written like that : `string.Format("[PREFIX]_{0}{1}",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"),userID)`.

But as it's processing multiple files in one second, I guess the file already exists. However, how comes it doesn't raise an exception such as file already exists ? 

Thanks for both of you !

EDIT : Going to miliseconds with `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffffff")` works